# Create radio button style in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tabs, radio-button

I'm new to ReactJS and I really want to know what is the best practice for creating a Radio button style. Actually kinda like switching between tabs. For example, I have a layout like this one [image]

When use click on each icon, it switches to its own tab.
I really want to know what is the best way to do instead of using pure radio button? Btw, the icon will have a image and div text inside of a div wrap. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to have a component that is your tab controller. Then that component tracks which tab is selected, and will render the selected component